# Vue JS : right click event directive

Tags: treeview, mouseevent, vue.js

I know these vue event handlers:

```
@click : mouse left-click
@dblclick : mouse double click
```

What could be the handler/directive to detect a right-click?
Need to implement a custom Context menu in Vue Tree view.

Answer (score 100):

```
<button @contextmenu="handler($event)">r-click</button>

methods : {
    handler: function(e) {
        //do stuff
        e.preventDefault();
     }
}
```

`@contextmenu` will do the trick. The `preventDefault` is to avoid showing the default context menu.

S*horter, as indincated in the comment :*

```
<button @contextmenu.prevent="handler">r-click</button>
```

Now the `prevent` modifier takes care preventing default behaviour.

**Edit:** For this to work with vue components, add a `.native` event modifier.

```
<custom @contextmenu.native="handler"></custom>
```

Comment: Use `@contextmenu.prevent="..."` to have Vue take care of `preventDefault`

Comment: Note: `.native` [has been removed](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/v-on-native-modifier-removed.html) in vue 3

Answer (score 1):

here is also the answer to the "custom" word - aka an [idea](https://codepen.io/yordangeorgiev/pen/GzWJzd) how to catch the right clickable elements' ids

```
<html>
  <head>
     <style>
        html, body, #app {
          margin: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          display: flex;
          text-align: center;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          background-color: #343338;
          font-family: Roboto, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        }
        .title {
          color: white;
          display: block;
          font-size: 25px;
        }

        .cls-context-menu {
           display:none;
           position:absolute;
        }
        .cls-context-menu ul, #context-menu li {
            list-style:none;
            margin:0; padding:0;
            background:white;
        }
        .cls-context-menu { border:solid 1px #CCC;}
        .cls-context-menu li {
           border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC;
           display:block;
           padding:5px 12px;
           text-decoration:none;
           color:blue;
        }
        .cls-context-menu li:hover{
            background: blue;
            color: #FFF;
        }
        .cls-context-menu li:last-child { border:none; }

        .context-menu-icon {
          top: 1px;
          position: relative;
          margin-right: 2px;
        }
        .cls-context-menu-item {
          cursor: pointer;
          display:block;
          padding:20px;
          background:#ECECEC;
        }



  </style>
       <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            href="../../poc/right-click-vmenu/right-click-menu.css" /> -->
  </head>
  <body>


  <template id="context-menu-item-template">
    <li class="cls-context-menu-item">
      <slot></slot>
    </li>
  </template>

  <template id="context-menu-template">
     <div id="div-context-menu" :nid="cid" class="cls-context-menu" style="left: 160px; top: 57px; display: none">
       <ul>
         <context-menu-item>
           <a @click="addNewItem($event)"><img class="context-menu-icon" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA0NS40IDQ1LjQiPjxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNmOTY5MGUiIGQ9Ik00MS4zIDE4LjZIMjYuOFY0YzAtMi0xLjgtNC00LTQtMi40IDAtNC4yIDItNC4yIDR2MTQuNkg0Yy0yIDAtNCAxLjgtNCA0IDAgMS4yLjUgMi4zIDEuMiAzIC44LjggMS44IDEuMyAzIDEuM2gxNC40djE0LjNjMCAxIC40IDIgMS4yIDMgLjcuNiAxLjggMSAzIDEgMi4yIDAgNC0xLjcgNC00VjI3aDE0LjVjMi4zIDAgNC0yIDQtNC4zcy0xLjgtNC00LTR6Ii8+PC9zdmc+" width="12">
            add new </a>
         </context-menu-item>
         <context-menu-item>
           <a @click="updateItem($event)"><img class="context-menu-icon" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA1MjguOSA1MjguOSI+PHBhdGggZmlsbD0iI2Y5NjkwZSIgZD0iTTMyOSA4OWwxMDcuNSAxMDcuN0wxNjQgNDY5IDU2LjcgMzYxLjYgMzI5IDg5em0xODktMjUuOGwtNDgtNDhjLTE4LjQtMTguNS00OC41LTE4LjUtNjcgMGwtNDYgNDYgMTA3LjUgMTA3LjVMNTE4IDExNWMxNC41LTE0LjIgMTQuNS0zNy40IDAtNTEuOHpNLjQgNTEyLjdjLTIgOC44IDYgMTYuNyAxNC44IDE0LjZsMTIwLTI5TDI3LjUgMzkwLjUuMyA1MTIuNnoiLz48L3N2Zz4=" width="12">
           edit </a>
         </context-menu-item>
         <context-menu-item>
           <a @click="removeItem($event)"><img class="context-menu-icon" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzMzkuMiAzMzkuMiI+PHBhdGggZmlsbD0iI2Y5NjkwZSIgZD0iTTI0Ny4yIDE2OS42bDg0LTg0YzUuMy01LjMgOC0xMS43IDgtMTkuNCAwLTcuNi0yLjctMTQtOC0xOS40TDI5Mi40IDhDMjg3IDIuNyAyODAuNiAwIDI3MyAwYy03LjcgMC0xNCAyLjctMTkuNSA4bC04NCA4NEw4NS44IDhDODAuMyAyLjcgNzQgMCA2Ni4yIDBjLTcuNiAwLTE0IDIuNy0xOS40IDhMOCA0Ni44Yy01LjMgNS40LTggMTEuOC04IDE5LjQgMCA3LjcgMi43IDE0IDggMTkuNWw4NCA4NC04NCA4My44QzIuNyAyNTkgMCAyNjUuMyAwIDI3M2MwIDcuNiAyLjcgMTQgOCAxOS40bDM4LjggMzguOGM1LjQgNS4zIDExLjggOCAxOS40IDggNy43IDAgMTQtMi43IDE5LjUtOGw4NC04NCA4My44IDg0YzUuNCA1LjMgMTEuOCA4IDE5LjUgOCA3LjYgMCAxNC0yLjcgMTkuNC04bDM4LjgtMzguOGM1LjMtNS40IDgtMTEuOCA4LTE5LjUgMC03LjctMi43LTE0LTgtMTkuNWwtODQtODR6Ii8+PC9zdmc+" width="10">
           remove</a>
         </context-menu-item>
       </ul>
     </div>
  </template>

  <div id="app" @click="hideContextMenu()" @contextmenu = "showContextMenu($event)">
    <div>
      <h3 id="title-1" class="title">Num-01 Click with right-a on body</h3>
      <h3 id="title-2" class="title">Num-02 Click with right-a on body</h3>
     </div>
     <context-menu></context-menu>
  </div>

     <div id="js_libs">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
     </div>
     <script>

  Vue.component('context-menu-item', {
    template: '#context-menu-item-template',
    props: {
      icon: ''
    }
  });

  Vue.component('context-menu', {
     template: '#context-menu-template'
     , props: {
        icon: ''
        , nid: null
     }
     , data() {
           return {
              cid: null
           }
     }
     , methods: {
        addNewItem: function (e) {
           var itemId = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.cid
           var msg = "UPDATE clicked for item-id : " + itemId
           console.log ( msg ) ; alert ( msg ) ;
      }
      , updateItem: function (e) {
           var itemId = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.cid
           var msg = "UPDATE clicked for item-id : " + itemId
           console.log ( msg ) ; alert ( msg ) ;
      }
      , removeItem: function (e) {
           var itemId = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.cid
           var msg = "REMOVE clicked for item-id : " + itemId
           console.log ( msg ) ; alert ( msg ) ;
      }
     }
  });

  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
     , methods: {
        showContextMenu: function (e) {
           if ( e.target.className.startsWith("title") ) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var menu = document.getElementById("div-context-menu");
              menu.style.left = e.pageX + 'px'
              menu.style.top = e.pageY + 'px'
              menu.style.display = 'block'
              menu.cid = e.target.id.replace(/title-/,"")
              console.log ( "cid")
              console.log ( menu.cid )
           }
        }
        , hideContextMenu: function () {
           document.getElementById("div-context-menu").style.display = "none"
        }
     }
  });
     </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```